# Calculating Box and Whiskers Values in SQL -- Using INSERT INTO vs. WITH <tablename> AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All,

I am attempting to calculate the Box Plot Values of Multiple Columns in differing Tables using [this forum post's](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=179251) methodology.

In the above link, the procedure only calculates the box plot values of one column using a `WITH SourceData AS` method to define a Source Table. So in order to apply this to all the columns for which I need box plot values,  I wrote a second procedure to repeat the first but changing the SourceData table from which the first operates by using an `INSERT INTO @SourceData` method.

Calls The Calculator:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [usp_Get_SKU_Type_Eff_BPVals] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Query1 nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @Query2 nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @BoxAndWhiskerVals table(
[Dur_Type][nvarchar](3),
[GroupID][nvarchar](50),
[Quartile1][int],
[Median][int],
[Quartile3][int],
[maxMeasure][int],
[minMeasure][int]);

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SET @Query1 = 
'
SELECT ''PRS'' as Dur_Type, L.SKU_Type AS GroupID,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, POL.Pick_Release, POL.Pick_Start) AS Measure      
FROM nelc.Pick_Order_Lines POL LEFT JOIN
     nelc.Line_ID L ON L.ID = POL.Line_ID
WHERE L.SKU_Type IS NOT NULL
 '
SET @Query2 = 
'
SELECT ''PSC'' as Dur_Type, L.SKU_Type AS GroupID,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, POL.Pick_Start, POL.Pick_Complete) AS Measure
FROM nelc.Pick_Order_Lines POL LEFT JOIN
     nelc.Line_ID L on L.ID = POL.Line_ID
WHERE L.SKU_Type IS NOT NULL
'

EXEC nelc.usp_Calculate_BoxPlot_Vals @SQL = @Query1;

EXEC nelc.usp_Calculate_BoxPlot_Vals @SQL = @Query2;
```

Does the Calculations:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [nelc].[usp_Calculate_BoxPlot_Vals]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@SQL nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SourceData table(
[Dur_Type][nvarchar](3),
[GroupID][nvarchar](50),
[Measure][int])

INSERT INTO @SourceData EXEC(@SQL);

-- Insert statements for procedure here

--Aggregate into a single record for each group, using MAX to select the non-null 
--detail value for each column.
SELECT Dur_Type,
    GroupID,
(Max(Q1NextVal) - MAX(Q1Val)) * Max(Q1Frac) + Max(Q1Val) Quartile1,
(Max(MidVal1) + Max(MidVal2)) / 2 Median,
(Max(Q3NextVal) - MAX(Q3Val)) * Max(Q3Frac) + Max(Q3Val) Quartile3,
    Max(measure) maxMeasure,
    Min(measure) minMeasure

  --Save into a separate table if desired.
 --INTO dbo.PreCalculatedQuartiles
FROM (
--Expose the detail values for only the records at the index values 
--generated by the summary subquery. All other values are left as NULL.
SELECT detail.GroupID, detail.Dur_Type,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q1Idx THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q1Val,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q1Idx + 1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q1NextVal,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q3Idx THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q3Val,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q3Idx + 1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q3NextVal,
    Q1Frac,
    Q3Frac,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = MidPt1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END MidVal1,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = MidPt2 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END MidVal2,
    Detail.measure
FROM
    --Calculate a row number sorted by measure for each group.
    (SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY Measure) RowNum
FROM @SourceData) AS detail

INNER JOIN (
    --Summarize to find index numbers and fractions we need to use to locate 
    --the values at the quartile points.
    SELECT GroupID, Dur_Type,
        FLOOR((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) Q1Idx,
        ((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) - FLOOR((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) Q1Frac,
        (COUNT(*) + 1) / 2 AS MidPt1,
        (COUNT(*) + 2) / 2 AS Midpt2,
        FLOOR((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) Q3Idx,
        ((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) - FLOOR((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) Q3Frac
    FROM @SourceData
    GROUP BY GroupID, Dur_Type
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

) AS summary ON detail.GroupID  = summary.GroupID 

) AS combined
GROUP BY GroupID, Dur_Type;
END
```

So the problem is that when I use `INSERT INTO @SourceData` instead of the `WITH SourceData AS` the query takes SIGNIFICANTLY longer to execute (I haven't actually waited to see how long but its over 4 hours). Where when one uses `WITH SourceData AS`, the query finishes in 1-2 minutes.

So my question is: Why does it do this if both are acting as a table to draw data from? And how can I repeat the calculation procedure on different columns without using my `INSERT INTO` method?

EDIT: This is using the WITH Statement. Works fine but I don't know how to run the procedure multiple times with this method.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [nelc].[usp_Calculate_BP_PRS]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
WITH SourceData AS (
SELECT 'PRS' as Dur_Type, L.SKU_Type AS GroupID,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, POL.Pick_Release, POL.Pick_Start) AS Measure      
   FROM nelc.Pick_Order_Lines POL LEFT JOIN
        nelc.Line_ID L ON L.ID = POL.Line_ID
   WHERE L.SKU_Type IS NOT NULL
)

    SELECT Dur_Type,
    GroupID,
(Max(Q1NextVal) - MAX(Q1Val)) * Max(Q1Frac) + Max(Q1Val) Quartile1,
(Max(MidVal1) + Max(MidVal2)) / 2 Median,
(Max(Q3NextVal) - MAX(Q3Val)) * Max(Q3Frac) + Max(Q3Val) Quartile3,
    Max(measure) maxMeasure,
    Min(measure) minMeasure

--Save into a separate table if desired.
--INTO dbo.PreCalculatedQuartiles
 FROM (
 --Expose the detail values for only the records at the index values 
 --generated by the summary subquery. All other values are left as NULL.
 SELECT detail.GroupID, detail.Dur_Type,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q1Idx THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q1Val,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q1Idx + 1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q1NextVal,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q3Idx THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q3Val,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = Q3Idx + 1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END Q3NextVal,
    Q1Frac,
    Q3Frac,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = MidPt1 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END MidVal1,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = MidPt2 THEN Measure ELSE NULL END MidVal2,
    Detail.measure
FROM
    --Calculate a row number sorted by measure for each group.
    (SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY Measure) RowNum
    FROM SourceData) AS detail

INNER JOIN (
    --Summarize to find index numbers and fractions we need to use to locate 
    --the values at the quartile points.
    SELECT GroupID, Dur_Type,
        FLOOR((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) Q1Idx,
        ((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) - FLOOR((COUNT(*) + 3) / 4.0) Q1Frac,
        (COUNT(*) + 1) / 2 AS MidPt1,
        (COUNT(*) + 2) / 2 AS Midpt2,
        FLOOR((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) Q3Idx,
        ((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) - FLOOR((COUNT(*) * 3 + 1) / 4.0) Q3Frac
    FROM SourceData
    GROUP BY GroupID, Dur_Type
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

) AS summary ON detail.GroupID  = summary.GroupID 

) AS combined
GROUP BY GroupID, Dur_Type;
END
```

EDIT #2:
Here are links to my sqlplan files:

[The WITH  AS Execution Plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XJeiyhYaFdQfpChYkUwDLK5_QmIEDJvW/view?usp=sharing)

[The INSERT INTO **Estimated** Execution Plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GWDpBITOKB27KP7K7jOFnx8rrwCC30Af/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT #3:
Added the Stored Procedure context

The `INSERT INTO` SP doesn't finish executing even when attempting only one `INSERT INTO` Statement.

Comment: Show us the Execution plans for the two different methods.

Comment: *This is using the WITH Statement. Works fine but I don't know how to run the procedure multiple times with this method.* ... are you running `INSERT INTO` multiple times? This may be reason for time differences. Is all this in one stored procedure? Please include stored proc, `BEGIN`, `END`, etc. lines to establish context.

Comment: Made Edits... 

The very top code block (lets call Proc A) calls the second code block (Proc B) twice with two different string parameters that will be used in Proc B's `INSERT INTO` Statement . Proc B only has **one** `INSERT INTO` statement where it takes the passed string and inserts it into an EXEC statement which passes the result back into the declared table @SourceData. Proc B is then supposed to do the Box Plot calculations on @SourceData but it never finishes execution.